# ASP .NET MVC 3 - Handle errors that occur in ActionResult DeleteConfirmed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, controller

In a controller a error with Create/Edit ActionResult can be handled with a try-catch block with the error being displayed on the view (via ModelState.AddModelError).

Now I am trying something similar with the DeleteConfirmed ActionResult but there is no error appearing on the view page.  The table I am trying to delete from should be complaining about deleting a foreign-key field value.

Should I RedirectToAction differently or add something else?

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                StatusList statuslist = db.Status.Find(id);
                db.Status.Remove(statuslist);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DataException dex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", dex.Message);
                return RedirectToAction("Delete");

            }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

Comment: How do you mean "there is no error appearing"? Does an exception get thrown at all?

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson - Question has been clarified.

Comment: probably the other two action methods have javascript that handle the displaying of a message once the result is passed to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a redirect, you lost the ModelState.
So you can do two things imo.

1. Setting the error message in [TempData](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications)["myerrorkey"] = dex.Message, so the message will "survive" for one redirect
2. Change your method and, in case of error, return a View so that the model state is not wiped out during the redirect

Personally I will choose the first. so you can think also to implement TempData in case of a delete telling the user, in the index page, that everything went smooth.